# Setting widths when using block elements to recreate a table

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to recreate a table using block elements (in this case an unordered list). I want one of those items to fill the parent element. This was very easy in tables. I'd just set the table to be 100% and not specify a width of whichever cell I'd like to fill the parent. How can I do this with block elements?

With tables it's easy:

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="200">200px</td>
        <td>nice wide column which fills the page</td>
        <td width="100">100px</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But using list items

```
<style>
    ul { 
        list-style-type: none; 
        padding-left: 0px; 
    }
    li { 
        float: left; 
    }
    .col1 { width: 200px; } 
    .col2 { } /* width: 100% doesn't work */ 
    .col3 { width: 100px; }
</style>

<ul>
    <li class="col1">200px</li>
    <li class="col2">tight column wrapping around this text</li>
    <li class="col3">100px</li>
</ul>
```

How can I make that center "column" fill the page?

Comment: Can you put up an example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of what the table looks like? I can't picture your problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
ul {
    display: inline-table;
}
li {
    display: table-cell;
}
.col1 {
    width: 200px;
}
.col2 {
}
.col3 { 
    width: 100px; 
}​
```

Proof it works: http://jsfiddle.net/zLvz5/

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would use javascript or calculate the width. But, with CSS, here is a bad solution:
use style for col2 (center column):

```
.col2
{
   margin:0 100px 0 200px; 
   float:none;
}
also, use add this style to col3:
.col3
{
   float:right;
}
```

One last modification:
Change the li orders so that center column is added last like:

```
<li class="col1">200px</li>
<li class="col3">100px</li>
<li class="col2">tight column wrapping around this text</li>
```

Again, this is a bad solution (imo).

Comment: Clever solution, but someone else posted the solution to use display: inline-table; and display: table-cell; which does the trick. Thanks!